# Every application's file open/save dialogue asks for "Keystroke Receiving" permission

Tags: permission, catalina

Is this a normal thing or I have some kind of plugins or applications which makes my requesters require this permission?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why *every* application would want this. I have heard that apps using JavaFX trigger this permission, even though they don't explicitly want or need it.

It's therefore possible that it is an unintended effect rather than an actual case of apps needing or wanting to monitor the keyboard input.

Probably best to deny and then allow if problems occur with the specific apps involved.

[image]

Comment: Always the application which displays the open/save requester asks for the permission. I really don't believe that every single app needs this permission, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Is it possible that you've set some Accessibility preference that might have triggered this?

Comment: Which setting can cause this?

Comment: @gklka I've updated the answer with some new information. Still not definitive, I'm afraid.